# In Android how I do the the picture moving?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make android program :--
[As like this picture.](http://www.ecigarettedirect.co.uk/ashtray-blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Heart.gif)

How can I make??
I have to try Animation??or video???
Pls just tell me the process how can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest method would be to use the AnimationDrawable class. The process is pretty simple. You would make a series of images in Illustrator, Photoshop, etc. showing the heart in its various stages. Then you would copy them to the /res/drawable folder in your Android project. Then follow the code examples [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html). As shown, you can specify the duration of each animation frame as XML code.

Comment: Its working..But there is a problem..i want this image as image_button..so the pic is coming like that :--http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/android-imagebutton-demo2.png

...My image is set to transparent image..i want just the picture no any background..how can I do that?